# Angular bootstrap animate.css remove animation

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, animate.css

In my project, thanks to animate.css, I can have entry animations like this:

```
<div class="row animated fadeInDown" ng-show="someCondition">
```

This is great.  When `someCondition` is true, the div appears with an animation.  What I don't understand is how to cause the reverse to happen.  Say, in my controller I set `someCondition = false;`.  What should I do in the markup to make the div do a `fadeOutUp`?

I tried putting the fade out in the class="" attribute, but that just conflicts with the fade in.  I also tried ng-class={} but I don't know what condition is true when something is being removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try a conditional [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
<div ng-class="someCondition && 'fadeInDown' || 'fadeOutUp'">
```

UPDATE:

Use a variable class name in your markup:

```
<div ng-class="someClass">
```

and add a watch to the controller to apply the proper class name:

```
$scope.$watch('someCondition', function(newval, oldval){
    if($scope.someCondition){
        $scope.someClass = 'fadeInDown';
    } else {
        $scope.someClass = 'fadeOutUp';
    }
});
```

In the following fiddle I added a setInterval to simulate the condition change:
http://jsfiddle.net/F52y5/59/

Comment: Just blinks away - no animation.  I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: When I remove ng-show, the div appears unconditionally.

Comment: I'm not a whiz with jsfiddle.  This one has my code so far, but even the fadeIn (which works for me now) doesn't work in this fiddle.  Not sure why.  http://jsfiddle.net/F52y5/3/

Comment: I updated the answer, try to see if it fits your needs